# Is it possible to find the range of $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} + 2x- 3$ without using calculus or a graphing calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The topic is combinations of functions.

Let $f=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ and $g = 2x-3$. Find the range of $f+g$.

$f+g = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} + 2x -3$.

Usually for complicated functions, you'd find the domain of the inverse, but this function does not pass the horizontal line test, therefore it does not have an inverse for me to find. The course I am helping out with requires the students to use calculators with no graphing capabilities.

EDIT: I know there's a minimum when $x=4^{-2/3}$ which results in $y \approx -0.619$ but I used calculus to solve. Since this is a precalculus course, I cannot teach that method.

Hope someone can provide assistance.

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: @Misakov: Unfortunately I am not.

Comment: Range can't be that. At $x=1$, $f+g=0$

Comment: @WinVineeth You sure? Because $4^{-2/3}$ is approximately 0.4 EDITED

Comment: When 0 is possible, $4^{(-2/3)}$ cannot be the minimum. At $x=1$, $f=1$ and $g=-1$.

Comment: @WinVineeth but $x=0$ is not possible because it's not in the domain of $f$

Comment: @SOULed_Outt, But I take $x=1$ which is surely in the domain..

Comment: @WinVineeth I'm sorry. I see what you're saying. I found the x value and didn't substitute into my function

Comment: Can you say something like- x rises twice as fast as sqrt(x). And hence, 1/sqrt(x) = 4x  for minimum... something on these lines would be the best possible without using calculus.

Comment: I will see how they respond to that. Thanks.

Comment: @WinVineeth That makes no sense.  $x$ does not rise twice as fast as $\sqrt{x}$.  And if it did, why would that imply $1/\sqrt{x} = 4x$ for the minimum?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, It's a crude approximation. In small intervals, $x^2$ rises twice as fast as $x$. That's why derivative gives $2*x$. Minimum occurs generally at the symmetric point. The function is $1/\sqrt{x} +2x$. Hence, $1/\sqrt{x} = 4x$ which is exactly what you get using calculus. Without using calculus, this I feel is the best you can do. I will gladly accept a better way.

Comment: @Muralidharan that should be an answer!

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Thanks. Posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum can be obtained by using AM-GM as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+2x &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+2x\\
&\geq 3\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}2x\right)^{1/3} \\
&= \frac{3}{2^{1/3}}
\end{align*}
The minimum is reached when $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = 2x$ or $x = 4^{-2/3}$

Comment: Note this only works because $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is only defined for $x ≥ 0$.